# How to define the right dependencies in .info, so drush can understand it?

Tags: 7, drush, .info

Currently in my [`booking_timeslots.info`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/booking_timeslots/tree/booking_timeslots.info?h=7.x-1.x) I've the following dependencies:

```
dependencies[] = date
dependencies[] = date_views
dependencies[] = hierarchical_select
dependencies[] = hs_taxonomy
dependencies[] = hs_taxonomy_views
```

which [fails](https://travis-ci.org/mycognitive/booking_timeslots/builds/88571817) with the following errors:

> No release history was found for the requested project 
>   (`hs_taxonomy_views`).
>
> No release history was found for the requested project (`hs_taxonomy`).
>
> No release history was found for the requested project (`date_views`).

when I'm trying to either enable the module, or installing it with `quick-drupal` command like:

```
drush qd --yes --core=drupal-7 testsite booking_timeslots
```

**How do I specify to which main project they belong to, so the installation process won't fail?**

---

Personally I know to which modules they belong, but I would like to automate this process, ideally by adding appropriate syntax into `.info` file so other services can understand its dependencies (such as `drush`). It seems running module in [Simplytest](https://simplytest.me/project/booking_timeslots/7.x-1.x) sandbox can recognise these dependencies fine.

I can't find anything relevant in [.info syntax docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/542202) apart of specifying `(major.minor)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare the project name of the dependency using the following syntax:

```
dependencies[] = project:module
```

However, this this is a [new feature](https://www.drupal.org/node/2299747) that was added in Drupal 7.40, and as far as I can tell, Drush doesn't seem to understand it yet.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds exactly what I need. Raised a new [feature request for drush](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1731).